# How can I remove partial duplicates in my MS SQL Database?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a database table which is automatically filled from different sources. Now I have the problem that there are some duplicate entries.

For example:

```
  EID  |  TID  |  StartDate  |  EndDate
--------------------------------------------
  1    |  1    |  20.01.2012 |  23.01.2012   
  1    |  2    |  25.01.2012 |  26.01.2012
  1    |  3    |  27.01.2012 |  30.01.2012
  2    |  2    |  20.02.2012 |  23.02.2012
  2    |  2    |  25.01.2012 |  26.01.2012
  3    |  1    |  20.01.2012 |  23.01.2012
```

As you can see, there are two rows in which EID and TID are the same. What I am trying to achieve is, that one the row, where the date is higher is deleted.
The only workaround I found, is a query where only the lower ones are selected.

```
SELECT EID, TID, Min(StartDate), Min(EndDate) FROM Table1 GROUP BY EID, TID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can  use a [`CTE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and the [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT EID, TID, StartDate, EndDate,
      RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  EID, TID ORDER BY StartDate, EndDate)
   FROM Table1 
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/33081/3/1)